# Volume Comma Issue Number

Tags: biblatex, biber

I would like to make some amendments for my bib appearances.
One of them is changing the article style.
This is what it looks like now: [image]

I would like the quotation marks to be removed and the volume and issue number to look like this 
[image]

This is what the bib entry looks like: `

```
@article{McMaster.1963,
 author = {McMaster, John},
 year = {1963},
 title = {The Takashima Mine},
 pages = {215--239},
 pagination = {page},
 volume = {38},
 subtitle = {British Capital and Japanese Industrialization},
 journaltitle = {Business History Review},
 number = {3},
 abstract = {}
}
```

This is what the bibliography looks like:

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIB
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 \usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear,
    sorting=nyvt
  ]{biblatex}
  \addbibresource{backmatter/sample.bib}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}
\renewcommand\postnotedelim{\addcolon\addspace}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
```

Sorry for these questions, I am rather new to LaTeX and still trying to figure things out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the drop-in replacement `ext-authoryear` from [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext), you only need a few more lines.

The punctuation between `volume` and `number` is controlled by `\volnumdelim`. The field format of the `title` with `\DeclareFieldFormat`

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

 \usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=ext-authoryear,
    sorting=nyvt
  ]{biblatex}

\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1\isdot}

\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{\addcomma\space}

\renewcommand\postnotedelim{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}

\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{McMaster.1963,
 author = {McMaster, John},
 year = {1963},
 title = {The Takashima Mine},
 pages = {215--239},
 pagination = {page},
 volume = {38},
 subtitle = {British Capital and Japanese Industrialization},
 journaltitle = {Business History Review},
 number = {3},
 abstract = {}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,McMaster.1963}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: McMaster, John (1963). The Takashima Mine. British Capital and Japanese Industrialization. In: Business History Review 38, 3, S. 215–239.//Sigfridsson, Emma und Ulf Ryde (1998). Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19, 4, S. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

---

If you can't (or don't want to) use `ext-authoryear`, the one line with `\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{\addcomma\space}` above needs to be replaced with

```
\newcommand*{\volnumdelim}{\addcomma\space}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\volnumdelim}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
```

of course you could cut out the middle man of `\volnumdelim` here if you want and can directly write `\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%` instead.

Comment: thank you so much! unfortunately that leaves me with an error message - do you know where I messed up?https://imgur.com/a/RCwEUhh

Comment: @user168390 Overleaf are still using an older version of `biblatex` and they don't have `biblatex-ext` installed. Use the workaround at the end of the answer.