# Omit Vol and Issue/No?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I get different formatting with different bib sources (like article, book), but none of them are correct in their current state.

So in books it shows the vol as Bd., however neither vol. nor Bd. nor any preceeding name should be visible. In articles it does not show Bd. or vol. however it separates the numbers by period: 
[image]

> 3.2, S. 1-2

I'd like it to be like this

> 3, 2, S. 1-2

Examples:

```
@book{Doi.1978,
 author = {Doi, Yutaka and Sano, Tetsuji and Tanaka, Itsuo},
 year = {1978},
 title = {Senkyo seido},
 titleaddon = {[Das Wahlsystem]},
 keywords = {Election law;Local elections},
 volume = {10},
 publisher = {Gy{\^o}sei},
 location = {T{\^o}ky{\^o}},
 series = {Gendai chih{\^o} jichi zensh{\^u}},
 abstract = {},
}

@article{McMaster.1963,
 author = {McMaster, John},
 year = {1963},
 title = {The Takashima Mine},
 pages = {215--239},
 pagination = {page},
 volume = {38},
 subtitle = {British Capital and Japanese Industrialization},
 journaltitle = {Business History Review},
 number = {3},
 abstract = {}
}
```

Do you know how to fix that?

```
  \usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear,
    sorting=nyvt
  ]{biblatex}
  \addbibresource{backmatter/sample.bib}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}
\renewcommand\postnotedelim{\addcolon\addspace}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
```

-> Also I found quotation marks in article titles, which should not be there (it is correct that they are NOT italic though)

Thank you!

Comment: I think I solved your `@article` issue in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/457579/35864, right? Can you show a short mockup of what you would like to see for `@book`'s `volume`?

Comment: Also, this is just a pet peeve of mine, so feel free to ignore me, but I really dislike it when people say that the output is *not correct* or *wrong*. The output is not really incorrect or wrong by any objective standard that could unequivocally be said to apply here, it is just not what you expect or want.

Comment: Are we talking https://www.uni-trier.de/fileadmin/fb2/JAP/Zitierregeln_und_Vorlagen/2017_Hinweise_zur_Erstellung_eines_Literaturverzeichnisses.pdf or https://www.ioa.uni-bonn.de/de/studium/materialien/formalregeln_ioa.pdf?

Comment: sorry for the fact that english is not my mothertongue and i did not articulate adequately. I know the problem is not the output itself but caused by my mistakes or missing knowledge. I just wanted to express the issue I have quickly. I have attached the bibliography example - it is the 3r entry (also shown in the bib entry examples starting with DOI)

Comment: @moewe IOA Uni Bonn :)

Comment: No to what? Trier or Bonn? Or do you mean that https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/457579/35864 did not solve the article issue? You don't have to apologise for your English (as far as I can tell is is brilliant; if I translate "die Ausgabe ist falsch/nicht korrekt/nicht richtig" into German the core of the issue remains; you should not feel attacked, I was just stating my disliking for phrases like this that are commonplace in German and English formus) and the issue is not that you are doing something wrong: The issue is that the default output is different from what you want.

Comment: @moewe I corrected the comment, I only saw the Uni-Trier URL at first, that's why I wrote "no", but it's actually the IOA Uni Bonn criteria I am trying to convert to LaTeX so I can start using it for all kinds of papers and finally my thesis :)

Comment: Mhhh, I just had another look at https://www.ioa.uni-bonn.de/de/studium/materialien/formalregeln_ioa.pdf and the Doi example has no `volume` there at all. On the other hand §10.2.10 Mehrbändiges Werk shows that `volume` should be given as "Bd. 1", so I think the current output is good.

Comment: thank you! I'll look into it again :) @moewe

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@article` issue was already solved in [Volume Comma Issue Number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/457579/35864), so we can focus on the `@book` issue.

As discussed in the comments, your guidelines https://www.ioa.uni-bonn.de/de/studium/materialien/formalregeln_ioa.pdf require "Bd." (*volume*) when a book is part of a multi-volume, see §10.2.10 *Mehrbändiges Werk*. So the output might be as required after all.

The fact that you used `series` in `Doi.1978` makes me think that we might be talking about a `series`+`number` here instead of `(main)title`+`volume`. These two combinations `series`+`number` on one hand and `(main)title`+`volume` on the other are the standard idioms in `biblatex`.

You use `series`+`number` for a books in a loose series (like Springer's [*A Series of Comprehensive Studies in Mathematics*](https://www.springer.com/series/138), see `liggett:ips` in the example below). The series might have a core editing team with only low fluctuation, but each book is usually authored by different people. Series can be extremely long-running and feature hundreds of books. While titles in series might be closely related, they need not be and loose series can cover a variety of subjects. This corresponds to §10.2.16 *Angaben zu Schriftenreihen* in your guidelines.

On the other hand `(main)title`+`volume` is for a specific volume in a multi-volume work. Usually all parts of the multi-volume work will be written by the same set of authors. If each volume of the multi-volume work has a title on its own you use `maintitle`+`volume`+`title` (see `markert` in the MWE below) where `maintitle` is the title of the collection and `title` the title of the individual volume. If the volumes don't have a separate title, you just use `title`+`volume` (see `schlesinger` in the MWE below). This would correspond to §10.2.10 *Mehrbändiges Werk* in your guidelines.

So I would use the following input

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{schlesinger,
  author    = {Arthur Schlesinger},
  title     = {History of {U.S.} Political Parties},
  volume    = {1},
  date      = {1973},
  publisher = {Chelsea},
  location  = {New York},
}
@book{markert,
  author    = {Alexander Markert},
  maintitle = {Geschichte Südostasiens},
  volume    = {1},
  title     = {Vietnam},
  date      = {1973},
  publisher = {Rückert},
  location  = {München},
}
@book{liggett:ips,
  author    = {Liggett, Thomas M.},
  title     = {Interacting Particle Systems},
  date      = {1985},
  publisher = {Springer},
  location  = {New York},
  series    = {Grundlehren der mathematischen Wissenschaften},
  number    = {276},
}
@book{Doi.1978.1,
 author         = {Doi, Yutaka and Sano, Tetsuji and Tanaka, Itsuo},
 year           = {1978},
 maintitle      = {Senkyo seido},
 maintitleaddon = {[Das Wahlsystem]},
 volume         = {10},
 title          = {Gendai chih{\^o} jichi zensh{\^u}},
 publisher      = {Gy{\^o}sei},
 location       = {T{\^o}ky{\^o}},
}
@book{Doi.1978.2,
 author     = {Doi, Yutaka and Sano, Tetsuji and Tanaka, Itsuo},
 year       = {1978},
 title      = {Senkyo seido},
 titleaddon = {[Das Wahlsystem]},
 publisher  = {Gy{\^o}sei},
 location   = {T{\^o}ky{\^o}},
 series     = {Gendai chih{\^o} jichi zensh{\^u}},
 number     = {10},
}
@book{Ito.1978,
  author    = {Itō, Masami},
  year      = {1978},
  title     = {Broadcasting in Japan},
  publisher = {{Routledge and Kegan Paul}},
  location  = {London},
  series    = {Case studies on broadcasting systems},
  number    = {7},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

\begin{document}
\cite{schlesinger,markert,liggett:ips,Doi.1978.1,Doi.1978.2,Ito.1978}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Doi, Yutaka, Tetsuji Sano und Itsuo Tanaka (1978a): Senkyo seido. [Das Wahlsystem]. Bd. 10: Gendai chihô jichi zenshû. Tôkyô: Gyôsei.//— (1978b): Senkyo seido. [Das Wahlsystem]. Gendai chihô jichi zenshû 10. Tôkyô: Gyôsei.//Ito, Masami (1978): Broadcasting in Japan. Case studies on broadcasting systems 7. London: Routledge and Kegan Paul.//Liggett, Thomas M. (1985): Interacting Particle Systems. Grundlehren der mathematischen Wissenschaften 276. New York: Springer.//Markert, Alexander (1973): Geschichte Südostasiens. Bd. 1: Vietnam. München: Rückert.//Schlesinger, Arthur (1973): History of U.S. Political Parties. Bd. 1. New York: Chelsea.]